# Reversing Characters of the Array in c++ - Here i am not able to reverse the input string

Tags: c++, c++14

I want to reverse the input string; this is the code I wrote, but I am unable to print the reverse of the string.

```cpp
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

void main() {
    char Title[] = "\t THE ANALYZER";
    char phrase[501];
    int charTotal = 0;
    int numTotal = 0;
    int letterTotal = 0;
    int vowelTotal = 0;
    int consonTotal = 0;
    int spacesTotal = 0;
    int specialCharTotal = 0;

    cout << Title<< endl;
    cout << "\t ____________" << endl;
    cout << " Enter your phrase (Max 500): ";
    
    cin.getline(phrase, 501);
    cout << " Thanks, Analyzing..." << endl;
    cout << " These are the informations about your phrase" << endl;

    for (int i = 0; phrase[i] != '\0' ; i += 1) {
        if (phrase[i] != '\0') {
            charTotal++;
        }
        if (phrase[i] >= '0' && phrase[i] <= '9') {
            numTotal++;
        }
        if ((phrase[i] >= 'A' && phrase[i] <= 'Z') || (phrase[i] >= 'a' && phrase[i] <= 'z')) {
            letterTotal++;
        }

        if (phrase[i] == 'a' || phrase[i] == 'A' || phrase[i] == 'e' || phrase[i] == 'E' || phrase[i] == 'i' || phrase[i] == 'I' || phrase[i] == 'o' || phrase[i] == 'O' || phrase[i] == 'u' || phrase[i] == 'U') {
            vowelTotal++;
        }

        consonTotal = letterTotal - vowelTotal;

        if (phrase[i] == ' ') {
            spacesTotal++;
        }

        specialCharTotal = (charTotal - (numTotal + letterTotal + spacesTotal));

    }

    cout << " Number of characters: " << charTotal << endl;
    cout << " Number of numerics: " << numTotal << endl;
    cout << " Number of alphabets: " << letterTotal << endl;
    cout << "\tNumber of vowels: " << vowelTotal << endl;
    cout << "\tNumber of consonants: " << consonTotal << endl;
    cout << " Number of spaces: " << spacesTotal << endl;
    cout << " Number of special characters: " << specialCharTotal << endl;
    cout << " Your phrase in reverse: " << endl'

    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [Minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (emphasis on minimum) showing us you've made an attempt at solving your problem. It doesn't look like any of the code you've posted tries to reverse the phrase.

Answer (score 3):

Make use of `std::reverse`:

`std::string s = "reverse me";`

`std::reverse(s.begin(), s.end());`

Comment: Or `std::string r(s.rbegin(), s.rend());`